# Optimize below query

Tags: sql

I have below table structure where header fields gets repeated for each line. I need to check for a particular invoice if the header is unique across each line or not. If not i need to get count of such occurances.

```
create table source_table1 (invnum, invamount,descr,linetype, amount, linenumber) as
  select 123,120,'desc1', 'ITEM', 100, 1 from dual union all
  select 123,120,'desc1', 'TAX' ,  20, 2 from dual union all
  select 446,220,'desc2', 'ITEM', 100, 1 from dual union all
  select 446,220,'desc2', 'ITEM', 100, 2 from dual union all
  select 446, 220,'desc22','TAX' ,  20, 3 from dual  union all
  select 500, 220,'desc3','ITEM' ,  220, 1 from dual
```

In the above example `invnum`, `invamount`, and `descr` are header fields which are repeating for each line. For `invnum` 446 we see that desc is not same for line number 3. So I need to get count of such occurances.

I'm able to write below query but just checking if there is any better way.

```
select count(1) 
from (
    select count(invnum)
    from (
        select invnum,count(*) 
        from source_table1 
        group by invnum, invamount,descr
    ) 
    group by invnum
    having count(invnum) > 1
)
```

Have come up with below query but checking if there is any better way of writing the same

Comment: What database **exactly** are you using? Also, to be legal, in most databases those subqueries should have alias names.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT invnum)
FROM source_table1
GROUP BY invnum
HAVING count(DISTINCT descr) > 1
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/INylMBJM

Comment: Thanks for update.what if there is a change in other header columns other than description

Comment: @Confused Add them to the `DISTINCT descr` expression.